# How to add a gradient to Iphone app and change color every like 2-3 second

Tags: ios, background

I am writing an app for iphone and I need to add a gradient background and be able to change it every like 2-3 seconds. I have looked up many places but I didn't find how to do it. I would really appreciate if someone gave me a detailed walk through on how to do it.

Comment: If you are writing an app for android, why does the question mention iPhone app?

Comment: i am so sorry I mixed that up. its iphone.

Comment: We all make mistakes man. As long as you fix it, you're fine! :)